# What is the correct format to pass array data into a solidity function call for processing?

Tags: solidity

I have deployed this contract to answer questions on a quiz on ethereum:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x2bf81e36060f2c4eb858e1212315f58a6f2cbc78#code

I submit my answers passing in this data

> ["1", "gas", "truffle", "ganache", "solidity", "metamask"]

and I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Which error are you talking about? The screenshot you shared showed several errors. The one about "Unexpected end of JSON input" I could not reproduce. When I passed the values you've shared here via Remix, the transaction happened (but reverted, presumably due to the hashes not matching).

Comment: From looking at the hashes in the code, I think you, e.g., hashed `"1"` to get the first value, but if you're passing in a `bytes32,` `"1"` will be converted to the (in hex) `0x3100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. The hash of that is `0x20463d390a03b6e100c5b7cef5a5ac0808b8afc4643ddbdaf1057c610f2ea121`.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue because when I check 1 answer it returns true here I am submitting via remix and MEW: http://youtu.be/nkQwa7t36N8?hd=1

Comment: I didn't see anywhere in your video where you "check 1 answer [and] it returns true."

Comment: But `checkAnswer` probably works, since it takes a `bytes` instead of a `bytes32` and thus doesn't get padded data.